# Android service to listen for incoming text from server

Tags: android

I need android service which will run in background and listen for urls from server.

Then that application will take data from urls and save it to hard disk.

My question in first place is, is it possible for android service to listen for incoming text from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is receiving push notifications, which can contain the URL's you want:

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+push+notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20push%20notifications)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for this 
http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

By using c2dm we can achieve your requirement.

Comment: Ok but one more question. Data which I want to send is from web form, let say first name, last name, etc. Is it possible when user fill web form and click ok, that data to be sent on c2dm servers?

Comment: definitely possible. I didn't worked in this type of apps.But i will give an idea.In order to submit the form user need to click on the ok button . For ok button implement the event listeners .by using that listeners (Before submitting the form) send the data to c2dm servers